# Macbuntu noobslab security

Tags: 14.04, themes, security, macbuntu

Is this site safe? Being sort  of a security nut, im Wondering if it is safe to install Macbuntu theme, and icon pack from noobslab.com.I have would not be installing any of the other things (lightdm, splash etc.)and, if it is not safe please point me towards alternatives that work similarly to this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The site is safe and used worldwide, but it is recommended to use only PPA's from Ubuntu or Canonical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for docky, it's just a bunch of data (xml and png), so for a certain definition of "safe" (if you already have installed PPAs) then, yes, it's safe...

Now, before you go ahead, please note that [one of the few vectors](https://thepcspy.com/read/linux-isnt-invulnerable/) for getting malware onto your computer is a PPA, so *never install a PPA because someone tells you so* (including me).  Always use your own personal judgement and do some research before installing a PPA!  Having said that, a PPA with 1000s of users mentioned in numerous articles is always better then installing `ppa:maffia.it/BotNet` with a few 100 users!  **;-)**

Comment: Dang, I better remove that maffia.it PPA, stat! :)

Comment: Simply adding PPA won't install packages, right ? And if I'm not mistaken, the apt-get command allows downloading source files as well as simply downloading without installing the packages. So if one wanted to check how safe those packages are, they could download the source or the files themselves and look through them

Comment: @Serg I already had a look...  :-)  (And if I would have known you would be having a look at this, I would have written `.ru` instead of `.it` **;-)  >:)**  )

Comment: @Fabby lol, I actually have the Macbuntu installed, so of course this question has attracted my attention. Hehe, I have even better idea `ppa:kgb.ru/spy`